# Writing on/inside the created 3d object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a 3 dimensional sphere object using Three.js and used a spherical image as a texture for the sphere but now i want to write some text on that object at certain position is it possible to do so ? and if ? then which constructor we can use for this...?

Comment: i think its a 2D text but even if you want to provide the info for 3D that could be even helpful...??

Comment: can anyone post their suggestions it could be great and helpful